# JavaFX: I need to get info from a TextField with a Button

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a text field:

```
TextField tfPost = new TextField("140 character word count...");
```

I also have a button with a ActionEvent Handler class:

```
Button btTweet = new Button("Tweet");
TweetHandlerClass btTweetHandler = new TweetHandlerClass();
btTweet.setOnAction(btTweetHandler);
```

Here is the body of the handler class:

```
class TweetHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Tweet button was clicked");
        String newTweet = tfPost.getText();
    }
}
```

What I need is for the string inside the TextField to be saved to a string variable when the Tweet button is clicked. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean "saved to a String variable"? Isn't `String newTweet` a String variable that is created when the button is pressed?

Comment: Oh yes sorry. That was not working for some reason. It said, cannot find symbol "tfPost"

Comment: Make sure `TextField tfPost` is an instance variable (preferably final) for the class. If it says it cannot find the symbol, you have a scope problem.

Comment: Ok so outside my main, I wrote private final TextField tfPost. It is still not working

Comment: Is the event handler an inner class or a top-level class?

Comment: Inside my class that the file is named after, there are two other classes / methods. One is called main and one is called start. It is in the start method

Comment: I added a potential answer. The problem, as @James_D pointed out, remains a scope issue which may be solved depending upon the particular class design.

Comment: Umm, huh? I meant is `TweetHandlerClass` an inner class, or is it a top-level class (i.e. is it defined inside the class that the other code you showed is in)?

Answer (score 0):

Variable scoping is a design question. The OP's question does not provide sufficient information to understand the full use case. One approach is to store the variable in the `TweetHandlerClass`. There are various rationales for and against such an approach. Nonetheless, for the specific question posed, it should suffice.

```
class TweetHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
  private final TextField tfPost;

  public TweetHandlerClass(TextField srcTxtFld)
  {
     this.tfPost = srcTxtFld;
  }
  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
    System.out.println("Tweet button was clicked");
    String newTweet = tfPost.getText();
  }
}
```

Then, in the instantiating the Button:

```
TextField tfPost = new TextField("140 character word count...");

Button btTweet = new Button("Tweet");
TweetHandlerClass btTweetHandler = new TweetHandlerClass(tfPost);
btTweet.setOnAction(btTweetHandler);
```

Comment: It'll work, but in any reasonable-sized application this strategy is going to create way more code and way more source files than you can reasonably handle...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the event handler to be a top-level class like that, you could give it a reference to a `TextField` as in @KevinO's answer. A slight variant on that would just be to have a reference to a `Supplier<String>`, which is more semantically what you really need:

```
class TweetHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private final Supplier<String> tweetSupplier ;

    TweetHandlerClass(Supplier<String> tweetSupplier) {
        this.tweetSupplier = tweetSupplier ;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Tweet button was clicked");
        String newTweet = tweetSupplier.get();
    }
}
```

and then

```
Button btTweet = new Button("Tweet");
TweetHandlerClass btTweetHandler = new TweetHandlerClass(tfPost::getText);
btTweet.setOnAction(btTweetHandler);
```

This is pretty much overkill though. Normally you would just define the event handler with a lambda expression, instead of an explicit class:

```
Button btTweet = new Button("Tweet");
btTweet.setOnAction(e -> {
    System.out.println("Tweet button was clicked");
    String newTweet = tfPost.getText();
    // ..
});
```